# Calculate hourly average from 1 minute data using script programming

Tags: linux, datetime, scripting

The following shows the txt file.  Column 1 is the datetime (starting from year 2008 to now).  Column 2 can be ignored.  Column 3 is the data.  The data is recorded per minute and there are some missing data.

```
2008-11-01 01:07:08,0,26.40
2008-11-01 01:08:08,0,26.40
2008-11-01 01:09:08,0,26.40
2008-11-01 01:10:08,0,26.30
2008-11-01 01:11:08,0,26.30
2008-11-01 01:12:08,0,26.30
2008-11-01 01:13:08,0,26.20
2008-11-01 01:14:08,0,26.20
2008-11-01 01:15:23,0,26.20
2008-11-01 01:16:08,0,26.20
...
```

I have to write a linux script to calculate the average data hourly.  The output file is like below:

```
2008-11-01 02:00:00,26.30
2008-11-01 03:00:00,26.10
2008-11-01 04:00:00,26.00
...
```

I'm not familiar with script programming.  Can you help me?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: As is now, this looks like "please make some code to me" and it is not welcome in [so]. Please read [ask] and then [edit] showing your attempts.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll try to edit the question.